# iPython Notebook for big / complex analysis. Good idea or not?

Tags: python, matplotlib, neural-network, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I'm working on a project involving Neural Networks (using theano) with a big data set 50,000 images of 3072 pixels. The computational process gets expensive when training the Neural Network as you may expect.

I was using PyCharm to debug and write the code but since I had some trouble using matplotlib and other libraries I decided to go for iPython Notebook. So far I'm just using it to do dummy plots etc but my main concern is : Is it a good idea to use iPython Notebook to run this kind of expensive computationally projects? Is there any drawbacks when using the notebook instead of just running a python script from the terminal?

I researched about good IDE's for Data Analysis and Scientific computation for python and I found that iPtyhon Notebook is the best but any other recommendations are very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter. It just runs a Python kernel in the background which is no different from one you would run from the command line.

The only thing you should avoid, obviously, is displaying huge amounts of data in your notebook (like plotting your whole image set at once).